# php/mysql query problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the following code ---

```
for($i=0; $i<count($strnamearray); $i++){
echo $strnamearray[$i]."<br />";

$cordcquery = "SELECT `lat` , `lng` FROM `traffic` WHERE `strname` = '{$strnamearray[$i]}' LIMIT 0 , 30;";
$cordresult = mysql_query($cordcquery);

if (!$cordresult) 
 {
  die('Invalid strncquery: ' . mysql_error());
 }

while($cordrow = @mysql_fetch_assoc($cordresult)){
    echo $cordrow['lng'].",".$cordrow['lat'];
    echo "<br />";
}
}
```

Here $strnamearray[$i] is an array which contains some name. there is no error showed after executing this php code. But the problem is i am not getting my desired output...

Comment: Well, that's helpful. What is in the table? What is in the array? What is the output you are getting? Why are you using mysql in 2011 instead of mysqli or PDO and prepared statements? Are you so eager to get an SQL injection attack?

Comment: @chx: There is little strict advantage in using `mysqli` over `mysql`, just a change of interface.  Not all code is OOP, nor should it always be.

Comment: First off, what does "$cordcquery" display? And can you run it manually? When I am dealing with SQL I always check that the query(ies) outputted can be entered on a command line or query window and run.
Second, this may not be any consequence,  but using "@" in front of a function suppresses error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark here with out some more information but two things.

1. `echo $cordcquery` just to make sure the sql looks right and you can execute it directly in MYSQL. From what I can tell it should but without knowing whats in the variables I'm not sure.
2. Instead of `LIMIT 0, 30`  use just `LIMIT 30`. Should be the same thing but I have seen some funkiness depending on what versions of php and mysql you are using with passing LIMIT **offset**, *row count*. From what I can remember it would take the offset and not parse the row count and therefore would not return any information.

Let me know if this helps.